# How to specify if a specific table is really used in the database?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am working on refactoring a legacy system. Its database has a huge number of tables where some of them are not used. I need to specify those tables in order to know if they should be deleted or not.
Is there any way in SQL to determine if a specific table is used or not by any programmable object (i.e stored procedure, view, or function)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on table -> View Dependencies

Comment: That sounds good. Let me expand my question a little bit and ask: is there a way to specify all tables in a specific database that have no dependencies on any other object?

Comment: Well, can you share it plz? I wrote in my answer below a suggested cursor which can output the dependencies on each table in the database. I am trying to make it more generic.

Answer (score 0):

In order to specify the dependencies on each object, I used a select statement that returns the object types: tables, functions, triggers, procedures, and views from my database.

After selecting these objects, I used a cursor to specify the dependency on each one of these objects. The following is my used code:

```
DECLARE c CURSOR READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT    name
FROM      sys.objects
WHERE     (type = 'U') OR (type = 'FN') OR
          (type = 'TR') OR (type = 'P') OR
          (type = 'V')
DECLARE @dbObjectName varchar(500)

OPEN c

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @dbObjectName
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
print @dbObjectName 
EXEC sp_depends @objname = @dbObjectName
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @dbObjectName
END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```